# Typing intersecting function parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, types, arguments, this

I have this factory function where first argument is constructor and the second is object parameters.

Is it possible to write a declaration of this function in TypeScript so that inside the first function there will be "available" methods from the second object?

Plus also that inside any function in the second object, "this" will be the same second object and it will be possible to call other methods?

The instance will contain methods from the second object.

(I don't know the names, what parameters and functions will exist)

**[TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEHsCdQUwB4EMC2AHANnANKAkqAHZxwAmoAxjNHBQC6gCWdAXAFCm0ZI2gBmAV0L1GkQvyT0YATwA8AFQB8ACjah1-IRRahlyugAtGAZx1JC0gJSgAvItAA3SI1KXsajWh6pT8tpZ0-NjYQUHkjYyZI40Z0DEY%20RjJNYTpRcT5oSBRQAGZoci9oOml%20GFAAdyMKA3xK8wYStEZCAHNjNkFU9IkpaGllLopcIp9rAG8PdSGAOjQsukgmuBmqQmM6aAE%202xSKAG4p0CO%20cuU1jdAAazhSltBRlGMJo40mPl1H4xmDJGMAeQqhAAClk0HBigMblYXm84RpZvMlktpOCANrQgC6uy%20GNumMO8PUAF8jqSjjQ6AJoOJiBU9odyaEAKrGOBMBinWAUGhIOjs8xMdZ0cwUOBsC4MFobUXsmy9Rb9QZaNJiXSwjSGExzMGReWTIllSA6ABEp0gJvchoARjxTbboCayYzcAaNK04HQoMa9qrCMoNfDKdTxFrvki0N9zYSNMSre7PQAhO2%209IB0BuoOekOgMM6yCRmYOmMk%20PqD1eyCQACChFIyegOiGfvTmbhwZpuYiMwr3vTAGou9qKw2AyXQKTiZZghdIFgZhhIK1lNKRcIVhGo1Xp7P54vl6vZT3PX3LDuxMY5yt9yvhUfe1Xa-WeAHLEA)**

```js
// For example, I need correct it:
declare function factory<T>(
    func: ((this: any) => void),
    params:T
): T


// This is simplified function from 3rd party for which I want typings
function factory(func, params) {
    func.prototype.constructor = func;
    
    for (const key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            func.prototype[key] = params[key];
        }
    }

    return new func;
}

// Use it for create an instance
const instance = factory(function () {
    this.props = {
        foo: "foo",
        bar: "bar"
    };
}, {
    getFoo: function() {
        return this.props.foo;
    },
    getBar: function() {
        return this.props.bar;
    },
    getFooAndBar: function() {
        return this.getFoo() + this.getBar();
    }
})

console.log(instance.props.foo)
console.log(instance.getFoo())
console.log(instance.getFooAndBar())
```

Comment: What is this code doing? Are you declaring a function or calling it? Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAyB1m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I am sorry I forgot add link to TS Playground. I edited post.

Comment: Please also put the full example code as plaintext in the body of the post.  Right now you still have `const instance = function myFactory(function() ...` which is invalid syntax.  A playground link is a good supplement to a question but does not take the place of having the relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: TypeScript isn't really geared toward strong typing or inference of es5-style constructor functions, so if you insist on using them you'll be required to use some extra type annotations to get it to compile cleanly. On the other hand you can use a `class` expression instead and get better inference.  Either way, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLlzem) would be the typings I'd give to `factory()`. Does that address your question?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: My goal is to make a hint. In "factory" is the first argument of the constructor function, where I would like as "this" an object that is inserted into "factory" as the second argument.


And in object methods (constructor's second argument), I'd also like a hint for "this."


Maybe they solved a bit of a similar problem in Vue 2. But my experience with generics isn't that great. And I don't know if what I want is possible.


I accept any changes in the code that would lead to the goal, but to make it compatible. ("factory" is the code of the third library)

Comment: I’m not sure if you saw the [TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLlzem) I posted in my previous comment.  Does the code there address your question and meet your needs or am I missing something?

Comment: I missed that link! That's what I needed, thank you very much.